# Reference to an "auto" function as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, auto, compiler-bug

Here is the minimal (C++14) code to reproduce the issue :

```
template <void (&a)()>
struct Foo {
    static auto value() {}
};

void bar() {}

template struct Foo<Foo<bar>::value>;
```

GNU C++ *"g++ (Ubuntu 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1) 5.1.0"* Compiler emits :

```
error: could not convert template argument ‘Foo<a>::value<bar>’ to ‘void (&)()’
 template struct Foo<Foo<bar>::value>;
                                    ^
```

The first weird thing I notice is `Foo<a>::value<bar>` — `a` is not substituted, and `value` has somehow become a template ?

The following nonsensical fixes reinforce my impression that this is a compiler bug :

- Declaring `value()` as returning `void` instead of deducing it
- "Dereferencing" `value` : `template struct Foo<*Foo<bar>::value>;`
- Parenthesizing `value` : `template struct Foo<(Foo<bar>::value)>;`
- Making `a` a pointer : `template <void (*a)()> struct Foo ...`

Finally, Clang compiles my snippet fine.

So, is there an obscure standard clause somewhere which forbids the first snippet, or has GCC just died on me ?

Comment: did you try it with clang?

Comment: @cookiesoft I'm on my way to trying it. Edit : it works !

Comment: I compiled it with clang (version 3.5) and c++1y and it compiled. Don't know, whether it compiled correctly, but it works :)

Comment: auto requires a trailing return type so this will work: static auto value()->void

Comment: @nilo Added clarification at the beginning : this is C++14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour has been deduced to be a bug, and has been filed on [GCC Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66766).